# Switch between readOnly and writeOnly databases using $useDbConfig in CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, model, cakephp-2.2

I have a master and slave database. To balance some of the load, I want all of my INSERT/UPDATE queries to go to the Master and all of my SELECT queries to go to the slave (since you cannot write to a slave without messing it up). I have the databases defined in the database.php. This is how I am trying to do the switching:

Inside the AppModel.php **beforeFind()**, I am setting:

```
$this->useDBConfig = 'readOnly';
```

Inside the **beforeSave()**, I am setting:

```
$this->useDBConfig = 'writeOnly';
```

However, after looking deeper I am wondering if the useDBConfig is a one-to-one relationship model-to-database. Meaning, maybe useDBConfig is only for pointing a single model to a single database, because this does not always work like I would expect. Sometimes an INSERT / UPDATE will attempt to run on a readOnly with readOnly permissions and fails.

If this is the case, how to I change my CakePHP application to send the requests to the appropriate databases? Should I be doing this a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you override all of the save methods (save, saveField, saveAssociated, saveAll, UpdateAll, delete, deleteAll, etc) in the AppModel and encapsulate the parent call between two setDatasource calls.

Comment: So Great! I had no idea where to start for this. Two quick questions: 1) Have you tried this on any newer versions of CakePHP? I think we're on 2.3.7 currently. 2) How do you handle production/development credentials? Does that get tricky with the two DB-setup?

Comment: @Emerson Yes. I am currently running this on 2.3.7. If you need help with the production / development config environments, you may want to take a look here: http://blogchuck.com/2012/08/custom-configurations-for-multi-server-environment-in-cakephp/

Comment: @ChuckBurgess: The link to the post which you have provided has expired. Can you update the link??